# Delayed_job: how to use handle_asynchronously to work with a function?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, delayed-job

The function is:

```
def createuser(name,pass,time)
   puts name,pass,time
end
```

I try:

```
handle_asynchronously :createuser("a","b","c")
```

and got a error:syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting keyword_end

thank you.

===EDIT===

user database in japen and web server in beijing. so i use this way to create a user.

```
def createuser(name,pass,time)
   Net::HTTP.get(URI.parse("http://www.example.net/builduser.php?hao=#{name}&mi=#{pass}&da=#{time}"))
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Can you now show the calling part. Where do you call handle_asynchronously? Just after the declaration? Somewhere else?

Comment: Hi. I'm using Unixmonkey's way.it's woring fine now. Thank you.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You don't need to pass parameters into the handle_asynchronously method, it is just a way to say your method should always be passed into delayed_job.

So in your example:

```
def create_user(name,pass,time)
  puts name,pass,time
end
handle_asynchronously :create_user
```

does exactly what you need it to.
When you call

```
create_user('john','foo',Time.now)
```

is the same thing as calling

```
delay.create_user('john','foo',Time.now)
```

I just setup a test app doing exactly this to test the answer, and here is the delayed_job serialized performable handler:

```
--- !ruby/struct:Delayed::PerformableMethod
object: !ruby/ActiveRecord:User
attributes: 
   name: 
   pass:
   created_at:
   updated_at: 
   method_name: :create_user_without_delay
     args: 
       - John
       - foo
       - 2011-03-19 10:45:40.290526 -04:00
```

Answer (score 4):

Why do you want to pass parameters to the method? Because the problem is * I think * that you are supposed to use it this way:

```
def create_user
  # do some delayed stuff here
end

handle_asynchronously :create_user, :run_at => Proc.new { 10.minutes.from_now }
```

Or

```
handle_asynchronously :create_user, :priority => 10
```

etc. (so without passing any parameters to the method that you pass as a parameter to `handle_asynchronously`).

**EDIT**

A delayed job is a long running task that you want to do asynchronously. handle_asynchronously is called one time, just after the method declaration, so passing parameters is useless because the code inside the method is sharing that scope as well!

Comment: I want passing parameters.like this `createuser("a","b","c")`.if i use handle_asynchronously i can't put parameters to createuser.

Comment: Yes, I think you can't that's the problem. I have browsed many examples using handle_asynchronously and none of them were passing parameters to the method. The question is where are you defining this method, why do you need to pass those parameters? What's the goal of doing it when using a delayed job?

Comment: See my edit. I am curious about this myself, may be we can do it what you are asking for but on a design point of view why do you want to create ONE user asynchronously?

Comment: Yes.i want to create ONE user asynchronously

Comment: It is not even a matter of number of users, but of passing 'constant' parameters to your method. If there are constant use them directly in your method without passing them. The handle_asynchronously method is called one time after the definition of the method. Can you show me what you are trying to accomplish? And take it easy :)

Comment: In other words, why passing parameters to a method that shares the same scope ?